# A lower bound for the $L^1$ norm of real trigonometric polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis

This question is somewhat similar to [Minimizing the L1 norm of odd-term trigonometric polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260077/minimizing-the-l1-norm-of-odd-term-trigonometric-polynomial). The context of the question is based on the paper [Hardy's Inequality and the $L^1$ norm of Exponential Sums](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007000). In that paper, they prove the inequality that given any increasing sequence $n_1, \dots, n_k$ of integers,
$$
\left\|\sum a_j e^{2\pi i n_j x}\right\|_1 \geq C \sum \frac{|a_j|}{j}
$$ for some absolute constant $C$.

A key idea of the paper is that they are able to construct a function $F$ such that

1. $\|F\|_{\infty} \leq 1$.
2. $\hat F(n_j) = \Theta(1/j)$ (This is the big-theta notation)

Can one extend this idea to give the same/worse bound for functions of the form $\sum a_j \cos(2\pi n_j x)$ where the $n_j$'s to be positive integers? Or perhaps is there a simpler way by saying something like
$$
\left\|\sum a_j e^{2\pi i n_j x}\right\|_1 \leq C(k) \left\|\sum a_j \cos(2 \pi i n_j)\right\|_1
$$ for some constant $C(k)$ that's not too big?

Concretely, can one prove:
$$
\left\|\sum a_j \cos(2 \pi n_j x)\right\|_1 \geq C \sum \frac{|a_j|}{j}
R$$ for some absolute constant $C$? Or maybe a worser bound?

Comment: For example, if I consider $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \cos(2\pi j x)$, I think the result from the beginning would give me a lower bound of something like $\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{n-j}|/j$, whereas the bound I seek is of the form $\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{j}|/j$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true.

Consider the [Fejer Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) $F_n$. From the explicit formula for $F_n$ we see that $$\|F_n\|_{L^1} \leq C $$ independent of $n$.

On the other hand since $ F_n = 2 \sum_{0\leq k \leq n-1} \left(1 - \frac{|k|}{n} \right) \cos(k x)$ we have that $$ \sum_{0\leq k \leq n-1} \frac{1}{k} \left(1 - \frac{|k|}{n} \right) \sim \log n.$$

Comment: Thanks so much! It’s interesting that there’s the lower bound for exponentials but not cosines!